# C# - Get Shared mailbox sent items folder object

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, office-addins

I am trying to fetch the Shared Mailboxes sent items folder from my outlook account. My current outlook account has two shared mailboxes. I need to fetch those shared mailbox sent items folder.

The below API call only retrieves the native sent items folder but not shared mailbox:

```
(Interop.Folder)m_outlook.Application.Session.GetDefaultFolder(Interop.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail);
```

Can someone please tell me a way how to fetch the shared mailboxes sent items folder?

Comment: It looks like you need to use GetSharedDefaultFolder. That, however, requires a resolved Recipient as the first parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [NameSpace.GetSharedDefaultFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.namespace.getshareddefaultfolder) method instead which returns a Folder object that represents the specified default folder for the specified user. This method is used in a delegation scenario, where one user has delegated access to another user for one or more of their default folders.

```
            Outlook.Recipient recip =
                Application.Session.CreateRecipient("Eugene Astafiev");
            if (recip.Resolve())
            {
                try
                {
                    Outlook.Folder folder =
                       Application.Session.GetSharedDefaultFolder(
                          recip, Outlook.OlDefaultFolders.olFolderSentMail)
                       as Outlook.Folder;
                    folder.Display();
                }
                catch
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Could not open the manager's sent items folder.",
                       "GetSharedDefaultFolder Example",
                       MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                       MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                }
            }
```